# How do you calculate a Vector from a Line Segment?

Tags: vectors, programming

I'm following this game development thread: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/90609/how-can-i-check-if-a-player-drawn-line-follows-a-path to essentially project a bunch of vectors onto some user drawn set of vectors (not sure if that terminology is correct).

Right now I have a series of line segments for both the character I drew: (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) and

character that users drew: (x3,y3) to (x4,y4).

How do I convert each (x1,y1) -> (x2,y2) set of coordinates to vectors? I found some conflicting information and couldn't figure out what the formula was. Right now I'm using
a formula like the below

```
func computeVectorsFromTwoPoints(point1: Point, point2: Point) -> Vector {
    let dx: Float = point2.x - point1.x
    let dy: Float = point2.y - point1.y
    
    return Vector(dx: dx, dy: dy)
}
```

Any help or direction is appreciated, thank you!

but I think this is calculating distance?

Comment: You are calculating vector components which is one of the ways to define a vector. Your function seems right to me. Please keep in mind that components do not let you to determine the starting point but an additional check can be done for this.

Comment: amazing, thank you @Vaysa